# How to display version number instantly

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to have the app version number displayed in my settings when the settings page is opened. My issue is that I learned that has to be done asynchronously. How do I get the version number and display it in a Text once it gets it?

My code that returns a future:

```
Future<String> getVersion() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

    return packageInfo.version;
  }
```

I want to display the version here:

```
ListTile(
     title: Text("Version"),
     subtitle: Text("1.0.0"), //replace with getVersion()
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use package_info to get the version of the app.
make state variable with dummy initialization and in initState make a function call to get the version value and update the state variable which is initialized with the dummy value

**My working code here**

```
//initialize dummy value
PackageInfo _packageInfo = new PackageInfo(
  appName: 'Unknown',
  packageName: 'Unknown',
  version: 'Unknown',
  buildNumber: 'Unknown',
);

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  //get package details
  _initPackageInfo();
}

Future<Null> _initPackageInfo() async {
  final PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  setState(() {
    _packageInfo = info;
  });
}
```

**Render list tile view as**

```
new ListTile(
  title: new Text('${_packageInfo.version}'),
  leading: const Icon(
    FontAwesomeIcons.codeBranch,
    size: 20.0,
  ),
),
```

you view will show somthing like **icon 1.0.0** which is specified as version in your package.

Hope it helps you. let me know if not

Comment: Good solution. Thanks!